# Why model.predict() from tensorflowjs always return same prediction?

Tags: typescript, tensorflow, ionic-framework, tensorflow.js, tensorflowjs-converter

I am making an app in the ionic 3 framework for recognizing handwritten characters and in order to do so, I am using tensorflowjs. The problem is that when everything is settled, the prediction always return the same value.

The model (converted from keras with tensorflowjs-converter) is stored locally in `assets/models/model.json`.

The images that I am trying to predict are extracted from a HTMLCanvasElement in which you can paint the character and then the function `getCanvas()` retrieves the ImageData from it:

```
getCanvas() {
    let photo = document.getElementById('MyCanvas') as HTMLCanvasElement;
    let ctx = photo.getContext('2d');
    const data: ImageData = ctx.createImageData(300,300);
    return data;
}
```

Then, the input tensor `[1, 32, 32, 3]` of the model is calculated from `data` and afterwards, I feed it to the model with `evaluateModel()`. In that function I load the `model.json` with `tf.loadModel()` and I try to predict the class of the image:

```
import * as tf from '@tensorflow/tfjs';

async evaluateModel() {
    imageData: ImageData = this.getCanvas();
    const modelURL: string = './../../assets/models/model.json';

    let img: tf.Tensor<tf.Rank.R3> = tf.fromPixels(imageData);
    img = tf.image.resizeBilinear(img, [32, 32]);
    img = img.expandDims(0);

    await tf.loadModel(modelURL).then(model => {
        const output: any = model.predict(img);
        const results: number = output.argMax(1).dataSync()[0];
        console.log(results);
    }
```

Everything works fine, no errors whatsoever, but when logging the output prediction onto the console it always returns the same value. Also, the array of predictions is very flat, pointing out that the model in python hits **99,01% accuracy on test**:

```
console.log(Array.from(output.dataSync())); 

17  /* Result of the argMax function on output */
[0.011652837507426739, 0.03457817807793617, 0.029257778078317642, 0.008851004764437675, 0.01691449247300625, 0.026485547423362732, 0.04974032938480377, 0.016473202034831047, 0.021701140329241753, 0.020724112167954445, 0.03173287212848663, 0.024661116302013397, 0.007072054781019688, 0.022814681753516197, 0.011404283344745636, 0.015105938538908958, 0.024694452062249184, 0.07453715801239014, 0.011547397822141647, 0.03946337103843689, 0.018134022131562233, 0.027423541992902756, 0.014102200977504253, 0.016702469438314438, 0.05513478443026543, 0.030478181317448616, 0.012863627634942532, 0.011269242502748966, 0.022525735199451447, 0.022545555606484413, 0.02840271405875683, 0.011758353561162949, 0.006561313755810261, 0.020660076290369034, 0.009705542586743832, 0.024312887340784073, 0.011940978467464447, 0.020643217489123344, 0.009319263510406017, 0.00957920216023922, 0.01844164915382862, 0.015434195287525654, 0.02170679345726967, 0.017867043614387512, 0.013763428665697575, 0.029312126338481903]
```

The only two things that come to my mind when trying to solve this problem are:

1. The ImageData is not correctly extracting the canvas drawing and because of that the prediction is always returning the same value.
2. The weights on the `model.json` are not being accessed or loaded, therefore the model returns the same value.

Any ideas?

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: The issue is related to how your imageData is generated. Please see my answer below !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`createImageData` creates a new ImageDate with transparent black pixel. Therefore, each time that the method is called, the same ImageData will be returned.

You rather want to redraw the initial image on another canvas whose dimensions (height and width) matches the shape of the tensor given as parameter to the model.

```
// create a new canvas on which the initial canvas will be redrawn 
const canvas = document.createElement('canvas');
// draws on the first 32 * 32 pixels
canvas.drawImage(photos, 0, 0, 32, 32);
// returns the imageData corresponding to the part of the canvas we drew
return canvas.getImageData(0, 0, 32, 32);
```

With this new imageData, it is no longer necessary to use `tf.bilinear`, `tf.reshape` is enough to give to the tensor the required shape.

```
img = tf.image.reshape(img, [1, 32, 32, 3]);
```

Comment: Hey! Thank you for the response. It makes sense to me, but the imageData is extracted from the context of the canvas, which is variant everytime you draw a character. So, createImageData is still creating the same ImageData object, even though the context of the canvas has changed? I will try the above code today, and I will let you know if anything happens.

Comment: It did help!!! Now the `output` array changes depending on the drawn character! But it does not reflect the 99,01% accuracy. But that is problem of my model, so thank you very much! [Now the model predicts in the browser - Google Chrome but in device the model is not loaded correctly and displays the following error: `Based on the provided shape, [3, 3, 132, 64], the tensor should have 18432 values but has 917`. I presume this is due to the model not being imported correctly...]

Comment: I am glad it helped. You can open a new question if you feel that it is needed. And you can give more details about the device used

Answer (score 1):

Just a small observation, hope it helps somebody. I was doing something similar where i was detecting hand drawn digits. In my case, the background color of my canvas was `White` and my StrokeColor was `Black`. As a result, I was getting the same prediction all the time. Later I just switched the colors, now my canvas background was `Black` and StrokeColor was `White`. Then it worked.